# How to use Visual Studio tabs to input command-line arguments into your build in debug configuration?

Tags: visual-studio

I need to debug my program by inputting command-line arguments (like switches) and jog my program to the break points.

I have tried to put my commands in the Build tab because I think it is related to link->compile->build->module. But I was wrong, I got `exit 9009 error code`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There it is -->

It is not in the build tab. It is inside a debug tab on Project Properties when you right-click on your project in your solution explorer.

[image]